# Open mml, bcf, fsif, msif files

Tags: windows

I have an old program (mymaillist and addressbook by avanquest software). It only worked on up to Windows Vista. I have Windows 10 now and my backup hard drive stored the data from this program in the following file types: mml, bcf, fsif, msif. Can I import this data into another program or otherwise get my information out?

Comment: Run Vista in a VM?

Answer (score -1):

Your old program can be opened under Win10.  Just reinstall it under the legacy program option.  Then copy your files to a directory directly under your userdirectory. For whatever reason, when you copy the directory into your Documents directory you get the message "Can't open for exclusive access, file is either open in another program or read only".

Comment: `"Just noticed your post when my mother couldn't open her Christmas list from last year and I looked for a solution. Didn't actually find the why but with this workaround my mother is happily posting Christmas cards. If you have problems respond."` Ok, I don't think he asked anything about your mother or her problem with Christmas cards! It would be wise to remove this part for achieving a high quality answer... Merry Christmas!